# Cocoapods: Unable to find an Xcode project to integrate

Tags: ios6, cocoapods

Trying to integrate cocoapods to existing project:

```
pod install
Resolving dependencies of `./Podfile'
Updating spec repositories

Cocoapods 0.16.0.rc5 is available.

Resolving dependencies for target `default' (iOS 6.0)
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (1.0)
Generating support files
[!] Unable to find an Xcode project to integrate
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the Xcode project in the same directory as the Podfile? If not, you should specify the location with something like:

```
xcodeproj 'path/to/My.xcodeproj'
```